# Touch or Click event ViewPagerIndicator in Android

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

May be duplicate of:

1. [Intercepting touch events in ViewPagerIndicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370729/intercepting-touch-events-in-viewpagerindicator)
2. [Disabling & Enabling Paging In ViewPager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134336/disabling-enabling-paging-in-viewpager-in-android)
3. [android: ViewPager and HorizontalScrollVIew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920137/android-viewpager-and-horizontalscrollview)

I am using [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) in my android app for swiping dynamic number of view and its working fine.

**What is want?** When user click on one of the slide its corresponding view will open. But i am unable to override touch event on **Pager**.

Activity code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseSampleActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.print(event.getAction());//not working

                return false;
            }
        });

        mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    }
}
```

I have searched a lot but didn't found proper solution.
But haven't got proper and brief answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a same issue. First I created a `CustomViewPager`, which extends `ViewPager`:

and override `onTouch` and `onInterceptTouch` events:

```
    public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {


        public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }   

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
            return super.onTountEvent(event);
        }

    }
```

Your xml should be:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="7" />
```

Change it to

```
    <com.yourpackage.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="7" />
```

For click event use `GestureDetector`. Sending `MotionEvent` to the tapGestureDetector.

```
tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new TapGestureListener());

    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                tapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
    });
```

If you are using the compatibility library, you can change the first line to:

```
tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new TapGestureListener());
```

You can handle your Event in the GestureListener:

```
class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

     @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
       // Your Code here
     }
}
```